# show $f_n(t)=t^n$ is cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

i am trying to show $f_n(t)=t^n$ is cauchy in $C[0,1]$ and $L^2(0,1)$. 
                   I can show $d(f_n(t),f_m(t))\to 0$, as $m,n\to 0$ .

How can i prove the question by using $d(f_n(t),f_m(t))<\epsilon$ ?  The metric  $d(x(t),y(t))=sub|x(t)-y(t)|$ for $C[0,1]$ and for $L^2(0,1)$  $d(x,y)=(\sum_{i=0}^\infty |x_i-y_i|^2)^{1\over 2}$ Thank you for your helping.

Comment: What metric are you using?

Comment: It can't be Cauchy in $C[0,1]$ because its limit would have to be in $C[0,1]$ and it is not.

Comment: Depends on whether $C[0,1]$ is complete under the metric - we haven't be told what the metric is on $C[0,1]$. @Nathanson

Comment: For $L^2[0,1]$ you can explicitly compute $d(f_n,f_m)$ in terms of $n,m$. Integrate.

Comment: Your definition of a metric on $L^2$ doesn't make sense. Where is the index appearing in the sum?